# bash extract a substring from "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT"

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

How can I substring a 1.2.3 from a 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT from bash?

I tried

```
echo '1.2.3-SNAPSHOT' | grep -o "^.*(?=(\-SNAPSHOT$))"
```

but it didn't work

Ideally I'd like a command to return 1.2.3 in both cases if the input is 1.2.3 or 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eg. use `egrep` like this:

```
echo "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT" | egrep -o '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]'
```

It cover the scenario you described:

> return 1.2.3 in both cases if the input is 1.2.3 or 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT

But I suspect the version could also be like : "3.1.33" (more digits in the third number), in this case just adding a `*` does work

```
echo "3.12.32-SNAoiashfsof" | egrep -o '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) should suffice

```
var='1.2.3-SNAPSHOT'
echo "${var%%-*}"
1.2.3
var='1.2.3'
echo "${var%%-*}"
1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed -ne's/^\(1\.2\.3\)\(-SNAPSHOT\)\{0,1\}$/\1/p' <in >out
```

...that will print *`1.2.3`* to output only for input lines which wholly match either of *`1.2.3`* or *`1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`*.

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

```
echo "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT" | cut -d'-' -f1
```